# Center a div and place it at the top of the page (CSS only!)

Tags: html, css

I've looked for this but can't find any good help. This is simple - I want to stick the div at the absolute top of the page and then have it centered. When I did `position: fixed` I also wrote `top:0px` and `left:0px` which then messed up the positioning. Help?

Comment: Please look up [Horizontal Align](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_align.asp) and [Postioning](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp)

Answer (score 1):

You need to set a width and then set `margin: auto` so it centers horizontally.

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  background: #eee;
}
.positioned {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 50%;
  margin: auto;
  background: #ccc;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p>Some text</p>
  <p>Some text</p>
  <p>Some text</p>
  <p>Some text</p>
  <div class="positioned">Content here</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `position:fixed` with `top:0px` - for the div to be in the top and with `left:50%` for the div to be in the middle.